# Force the execution of a function before exception handling (JAVA)

Tags: java, exception, execution

I am currently working on a big project (multiples sources files). I would like to fix an abnormal behavior by adding a function execution before the program's stop with exception (I mean I have to add this fonctionnality into a lots of existing functions). Is-it a simple solution (avoiding adding a line for each function) to force the execution ?

thanks a lot

Comment: if you are using framework like spring, maybe use AOP module and provide point-cut where you want a particular thing to happen.

Comment: It would be good to provide some specific example of code you are trying to implement or you have already tried..it helps in answering your specific needs

Answer (score 1):

Tis is the perfect use case for *aspect oriented programming* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Answer (score 0):

> before the program's stop with exception

You can use [addShutdownHook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) method.